# Way to create and fill arrays at set length in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, javascript-objects

For example:

I have 100+ `location` objects, each containing `latitude: x, longitude: x` values. These are in one long `array`.

I am using these with the Google distance matrix API to calculate nearby **stores** for my user. The problem is this API has a limit of 25 destinations per request, so I can't use my `array` of `location` objects as it is too big.

I am looking for a way to make multiple `arrays` at a max length of 25, and when that `array` fills, create a new one. A function that does this would be best, so that it works for any number of **stores**.

Comment: Can post code so far if needed for more context.

Comment: I don't think you can limit arrays to a certain size. Maybe if you use a proxy?

Comment: Are you looking for [chunking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8495687/split-array-into-chunks)?

Comment: `a = new Proxy([], {
  set (arr, key, value) {
  if (arr.length < 26) {
     arr[key] = value;
     return value;
    }

  throw new Error('Max number of items reached. Arrays cannot contain more than 25 items.');
  }
});` - this might be helpful?

Comment: Did you know that you can [slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice) your array?

Comment: Sounds like you need to create a recursive function that calls on itself once the the size has reached 25 and create new array. Give some code so people can help you easily

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about that:

```js
const locationObjects = [
    {latitude: 1, longitude:1},
    {latitude: 2, longitude:2},
    {latitude: 3, longitude:3},
    {latitude: 4, longitude:4},
    {latitude: 5, longitude:5},
    {latitude: 6, longitude:6},
    {latitude: 7, longitude:7},
    {latitude: 8, longitude:8},
    {latitude: 9, longitude:9},
    {latitude: 10, longitude:10},
    {latitude: 11, longitude:11},
    {latitude: 12, longitude:12},
    {latitude: 13, longitude:13},
    {latitude: 14, longitude:14},
    {latitude: 15, longitude:15},
    {latitude: 16, longitude:16},
    {latitude: 17, longitude:17},
    {latitude: 18, longitude:18},
    {latitude: 19, longitude:19},
    {latitude: 20, longitude:20},
    {latitude: 21, longitude:21},
    {latitude: 22, longitude:22},
    {latitude: 23, longitude:23},
    {latitude: 24, longitude:24},
    {latitude: 25, longitude:25},
    {latitude: 26, longitude:26},
]

let locations = [];
while(locationObjects.length){
    locations.push(locationObjects.splice(0, 25))
}
console.log(locations)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use array of arrays to store you location objects, every time an index with filled with an array of 25 elements, push new array into the main array and then start pushing new locations into that until you reach 25. something like this maybe?

```
let locations = [[]];
let currentIndex = 0;

function addLocation(location) {
    if (locations[currentIndex].length < 24) {
        locations[currentIndex].push(location);
    } else {
        locations.push([]);
        locations[currentIndex++].push(location); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution that uses a helper function called `handleArrayInChunks`, which calls itself recursively as needed.

It takes four arguments: the original ("big") array, the chunk size, a `chunkHandler` function to call with each chunk, and an optional `currentIndex`, which defaults to zero.

See the in-code comments for further explanation.

```js
// Defines an array of 110 items
const genericArray = Array.from({ length: 110 }).fill("someLocationObject");

// Invokes handleArrayInChunks (w/ default `currentIndex` value)
handleArrayInChunks(genericArray, 25, sendToGoogle);

// Defines handleArrayInChunks function
function handleArrayInChunks(bigArray, chunkSize, chunkHandler, currentIndex = 0){

  // Makes an array no larger than `chunkSize`
  let
    remainingCount = bigArray.length - currentIndex,
    nextChunkLength = Math.min(remainingCount, chunkSize),
    nextChunk = bigArray.slice(currentIndex, currentIndex + nextChunkLength);

  // Invokes the callback function to handle this chunk
  chunkHandler(nextChunk);

  // Sets the index for the next chunk
  currentIndex += chunkSize;

  // Calls handleArrayInChunks again if we aren't finished
  if(currentIndex < bigArray.length){
    handleArrayInChunks(bigArray, chunkSize, chunkHandler, currentIndex);
  }
}

// Defines a function to use as the chunkHandler function
function sendToGoogle(smallArray){
  console.log("passing " + smallArray.length + " items to API");
  // Here, call the desired API method with this chunk
}
```